# How to see if a unique constraint is added to a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a table in postgresql and added a unique constraint to one of its columns. How do I make sure that this constraint is added? How to check other unique constraints on columns of a table?

I would like to do this in psql terminal interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\d <table_name>`, e.g.:

```
create table test (id int primary key, str text);
alter table test add constraint test_str_unique unique (str);
\d test

     Table "public.test"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer | not null
 str    | text    | 
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "test_str_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pgAdmin, you can see all constraints added in the tables

For test table, you can see this in object browser as below

```
Tables (2)  
  test  
    Columns  
    Constraints  
    Indexes  
    Rules  
    Triggers
```

Expand Constraints and you can not notice all the constraints added to the table test

Comment: What about the terminal interface?